# Does swapping two variables using the destructuring assignment not work with ES2022 method at() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es2022

So I wanted to swap the first and the last items of an array with the destructuring assignment. I tried using the ES2022 method `array.at()` to get the values of indexes:

```js
const array = ['a, 'i', 'r'];
[array.at(0), array.at(-1)] = [array.at(-1), array.at(0)];
```

But when I run this, the SyntaxError is printed out to the console:

```
[array.at(0), array.at(-1)] = [array.at(-1), array.at(0)];
 ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
```

I then changed the `array.at()` methods to classic `array[]` and now the swapping works correctly without any errors:

```js
[array[0], array[array.length - 1]] = [array[array.length - 1], array[0]];

console.log(array); // ['r', 'i', 'a']
```

Could someone tell me what the problem with swapping with destructuring assignment using `array.at()` might be?

Comment: The difference is that `array.at(0) = 1` does not work, but `array[0] = 1` does.

Comment: `array.at()` is just a function call. JavaScript has no concept of pointers or references (not in this sense anyway), so assigning to the return value of a function doesn't make sense, and as such it is not valid. So, `array.at()` can only be used to read an array element, but not to write it.

Comment: as the comment above says you cannot a new assign value using at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid to assign a value to a function call:

```js
function sayHey() {
  return 'Hey';
}

sayHey() = 'Hello'; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

P.S. Thanks to [FZs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8376184/fzs) from comments for explaining this.